# Linked list insert with recursion trouble

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list

So I'm trying to create a linked list in C++ out of a list container class. The list class contains the member head (a node), and insert function, and the node class contains the data I need to add (first name, last name, age). However, I don't think I'm actually creating a list, rather just writing over p during the input loop

Here's the while-loop in the main program that reads data from a file

```
while(!infile.eof())
    { infile >> first >> last >> age;

// Process if okay

      if(infile.good())
        a.insert(first,last,age);
    };
```

Here's the actual insert function definition

```
void list::insert(string first, string last, int age)

{
    node *p;
    p = new node;
    p->first = first;
    p->last = last;
    p->age = age;
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = p;
        head->put(cout);
    } else
    {
        if (head->next != NULL)
        {
            head->put(cout);
            insert((p->next)->first, (p->next)->last, (p->next)->age);
        } else
        {
            p->next = p;
            p->put(cout);
        }
    }
}
```

I can't change the Node header or main program, so I need to use these parameters in the function calls. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the question? There is a `std::list` container in the Standard C++ Library.

Comment: I want to know specifically if I'm actually creating a linked list, or just overwriting p. When I use a while loop to traverse through, it only displays one node

Comment: I think it's this line that's giving me trouble

insert((p->next)->first, (p->next)->last, (p->next)->age);

Comment: SO is not about code review. If you have a working code please consider Code Review SE site. Avoid cross posting if you decide to go there. As-is it is unclear what the question is. Please try to [clarify](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48915702/edit).

Comment: If we only had a penny for each linked list insert bug.

Comment: @LukeClover The code should be rewritten, it doesn't do anything sensible, it's not close to being correct. I guess you don't have a good grasp of pointers yet (or recursion). I'll make two suggestions, first is that you draw out on paper with boxes and arrows what happens when your code executes. If you do this correctly it won't take long to see your errors. The second suggestion is to question why you are using recursion. It's not normal to use recursion for this task, I don't see that it adds anything, but maybe you have been told to use it.

Comment: @LukeClover The answer to your question is that yes you are not adding to the list after the first item (as far as I can judge from the partial code here).

Comment: @john I did a very similar example earlier that created a list successfully, so I was trying to write is as similar to that

Here's the original function call from inside a while-loop
if(infile.good())
        {
            p = new node(name, count);
            if (head == NULL)
                head = p;
            else
                head ->append(p);
        };

Comment: Here is the original function definition
{
    if(next!=NULL)
        next->append(p);
    else
        next = p;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inserting a node in a linked list is simple when the list is empty.

```
head = p;
```

and you are done.

Inserting a node at the end of linked list is a little bit involved when the list is not empty. Pictorially, let's say you have:

[image: Current Linked List]

and you want to add a new node at the end. You will need to make the link between the last node of the existing linked list and the new node so that you will end up with:

[image: New Linked List]

In order to be able to do that you have to walk the linked list to get to the last node. Then, you can use:

```
lastNode->next = p;
```

and you are done.

Ignoring the calls to create the output, here's what your function would look like.

```
void list::insert(string first, string last, int age)
{
   node *p = new node;
   p->first = first;
   p->last = last;
   p->age = age;

   if (head == nullptr)
   {
      // The simple case
      head = p;
   }
   else
   {
      // Gather the last node in the linked list.
      node* lastNode = head;
      while ( lastNode->next != nullptr )
      {
         lastNode = lastNode->next;
      }

      lastNode->next = p;
   }
}
```

---

Using recursion for inserting a node looks very different. Here's an untested suggestion:

```
void list::insert(node*& ptr, node* p)
{
   if ( ptr == nullptr )
   {
      ptr = p;
   }
   else
   {
      insert(ptr->next, p);
   }
}

void list::insert(string first, string last, int age)
{
   node *p = new node;
   p->first = first;
   p->last = last;
   p->age = age;

   insert(head, p);
}
```

**I don't recommend using the recursive method.** It not only takes away the readability of the algorithm but is also more expensive at run time. If you have a linked list with a large number of items in it, it might even lead to stack overflow.

Comment: Thanks for that. My struggle was trying to find a relation between the last item in the list and the new node